# AWS cognito ASP.NET Core MVC throws 'invalid_client'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm working on implementing user authentication on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC website. The site will be hosted on AWS lambda so I've decided to use AWS cognito.

I'm following the aws sample [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-netcore-aspnetmvc-amazon-cognito-authentication-authorization-samples) word for word (in testing, I've cloned their repository and applied my own `appsettings.json` and created the cognito pool and app client exactly as described. The only difference being (to the best of my knowledge) the callback url is incorrect in the sample, so I'm using `https://localhost:5001/signin-oidc` rather than `https://localhost:5001/externalauthentication/callback` (I have also tried this obviously it doesn't work).

A description of the error is:

- Start the application locally (http://localhost:5001) and click "products"
- I'm then taken to the default cognito login page, I enter my username/password
- Redirection back to localhost occurs but I'm shown an exception page with the following exception:

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

My appsettings is 1:1 as per their example, I've manually recreated the pool and app client numerous times in case I missed something or made a mistake copying id's etc and have hit the same problem every time.

I'm assuming 'invalid_client' isn't referring to the 'client_id' as mentioned, I've recreated this many times and triple checked it's correct in my `appsettings.json`.

All help is much appreciated

Comment: Same issue when following https://www.faciletechnolab.com/blog/2021/4/21/how-to-implement-aws-cognito-authentication-in-aspnet-core-50-web-application-

Answer (score 4):

For anyone following the same guide from aws, there's a very important peice of the puzzel missing from their page:

Under app integrations for your pool, click show client secret and copy this to your appsettings.json like so:

```
"ClientSecret": "#####",
```

Then add the clientsecret option to openIdConnect like so:

```
options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientSecret"];
```

Make sure the user you have created is inside the admin group and the callback url is correct:

```
/signout-callback-oidc
```

And all should be good in the world of cognito and aspnet core